# Using Mongoose types only

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose

I am developing a package in TypeScript that includes all required types within the repository.

Is it possible to use the types provided by the `mongoose` package as dev dependencies?
All I want is to specify the `ObjectId` type.

I noticed that the `@types/mongoose` package is **deprecated**, so what are my options for accessing the types in this situation?

Comment: What is the concern with installing `mongoose` as a devDependencies?

Comment: that would still cause problems during development because mongoose runs on initialization. i.e. if you are running mongoose as a devDependency in a browser enviornment then importing it, even if declared with the type keyword would still result in errors during development.

Answer (score -1):

I am using mongoose with typescript and have defined the type of `ObjectId` from the mongoose library and it is working fine.

```
import { Types } from 'mongoose';
```

and there is type `Types.ObjectId` which you can use as a type

Comment: The question is how to prevent of installing the entire package if I need only this type